# In which community can I ask for advice about which versioning software to use for particular project type?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I am doing a Master's thesis and trying to decide the best way to organize my MATLAB data processing files. I want to ask for advice on the best versioning system to use.

What would be the appropriate community?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The appropriate site to ask this might be [**SE Software Recommendations**](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Be sure to fulfill at least these policies when asking a question there (from the [help center](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)):

> Good software recommendation requests have two components:
>
> - A purpose — a task to accomplish, a user story
> - Some objective requirements — a minimum set of features